# Number formats in AWS Athena output

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, presto, trino

I'm running a simple query in Athena and looking at the output on the screen.

```
SELECT 
grd_ind,
SUM(CTE_TDE.Exposure_Premium) AS exposure_prem

FROM
CTE_TDE 

GROUP BY grd_ind
```

And the output looks like this:

| grd_ind | exposure_prem |
| --- | --- |
|  | 5.684367495549501E8 |
| 1 | 1.7319064403171487E9 |

How do I get the output numbers in a easy-to-read comma delimited form?

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `format` (if you don't mind possible extra zeroes in decimal part, works in Trino):

```sql
select format('%,.8f', 1.7319064403171487E9);
```

Output:

```
         _col0
------------------------
 1,731,906,440.31714870
```